# How would I go about printing on plastic lids?

Tags: print-design

How would I go about printing my own branding on black PET plastic lids, like in the picture? How is that achieved and what type of printing is that? 
[image: plastic lid]

Comment: Have you contacted print providers and asked them?

Answer (score 2):

This is screen printing. You could find a local shop that does things like plaques, mementos, trophies, etc.. Most such places screen print many of their items, so you'd just find one that does, give them a sample and ask them for a quote.

If you're contracting with a packaging house to fill the jars, they probably also have the facility to screen print the lids as well as print and/or apply labels. (I've never encountered one that didn't.)

The artwork would be created in InDesign or Illustrator and supplied in whatever format the provider indicates they prefer.